# Siamese Neural Network , RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [20 x 5], m2: [10 x 5] at ..\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:41

Tags: python, pytorch, siamese-network

I am trying to build a Siamese Neural Network with following code

```
class MySiameseNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySiameseNet,self).__init__()
        self.nn = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(30,30),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(30,10),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(10,5),
                nn.ReLU())
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(10,5),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(5,1),
                nn.Sigmoid())
        
    def forward_once(self,x):
        output = self.nn(x)
        return output
    def forward(self,input1,input2):
        output1 = self.forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(input2)
        combinedOutput = torch.cat((output1,output2))
        output = self.fc(combinedOutput)
        return output
```

The code works pretty fine when I give it to some random input like following

```
size=100
features=30
trainData1 = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(size,features)).type(torch.float)
trainData2 = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(size,features)).type(torch.float)
labelData = [np.random.randint(0,2) for i in range(size)] 

myNet = MySiameseNet()
result = myNet(trainData1[0],trainData2[0])
result
```

But the problem occurs when I try to give it all the data at once , because in case of batch wise input I would be feeding it not just one by one input but a batch of input values. So I tried first the following way

```
result = myNet(trainData1,trainData2)
```

I got the following scary error

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [200 x 5], m2: [10 x 5] at ..\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:41
```

Then I tried to use the Pytorch Dataloader method to give the data batchwise using the following way

```
class MySiameseDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
def __init__(self,input1,input2,label):
    super(MySiameseDataset,self).__init__()
    self.input1 = input1
    self.input2 = input2
    self.label = label
def __len__(self):
    return self.input1.shape[0]
def __getitem__(self,index):
    return self.input1[index],self.input2[index],self.label[index]

myDataset = MySiameseDataset(trainData1,trainData2,labelData)
myDatasetLoader = DataLoader(myDataset,batch_size=10,shuffle=False)
binaryLossFunction = nn.BCELoss()
adamOptimizer = torch.optim.Adam(myNet.parameters(),lr=0.001)
```

So now the Dataloader is working fine and I am being able to access data and label batch wise

```
for firstInput,secondInput,labelValue in myDatasetLoader:
    print(i.shape,j.shape,labelValue.shape,labelValue.shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10, 30]) torch.Size([10]) torch.Size([10])
```

But Now when I try to use the model for training using the following code

```
for firstInput,secondInput,labelValue in myDatasetLoader:
    adamOptimizer.zero_grad()
    output = myNet(firstInput,secondInput)
    binaryLossFunction(output,labelValue)
    binaryLossFunction.backward()
    adamOptimizer.step()
```

I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [20 x 5], m2: [10 x 5] at ..\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:41
```

Please guide me how to reslove the issue and how to pass the input batch wise to the models in pytorch ?

Comment: I guess the `cat`ing is happening along the wrong dimension? shouldn't it be `combinedOutput = torch.cat((output1,output2), dim=1)`?

Comment: That works for batch but does not work for single input case. I need a generic tweak that can work on both batch and on single input. By single input I mean this,  result = myNet(trainData1[0],trainData2[0])

Comment: the input to a linear layer has to be of form batch size by num features, even if the batch size is one, so, I suggest `unsqueeze`ing the single input before passing it in.